# file works fine on windows but doesn't exist on andoid (MAUI)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-maui

I am trying to write a MAUI program that reads text from a text file and uses it in a list:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    static string filePath = @"Resources\Raw\topics.txt";
    static List<string> topics = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

    Random random = new Random();
     
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label.Text = "press the white button and start chatting";
    }

    private void next_Clicked(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.Next(topics.Count);
        
        if (topics.Count != 0)
        {
            label.Text = topics[randomIndex];
            topics.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            label.Text = "Sorry.." +
                "\nwe ranout of topics";
        }
    }
}
```

the code works just fine when I run it on windows, but when I run it on android I get this exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

so I started debugging and found that the the exception was thrown because the file didn't
exist on android so I which I don't get because I'm 100% sure that I added the file as
a MAUI asset.

here is my csproj file and file structure:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>salfaty</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>Salfaty</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.salfaty</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>537C4D54-BA75-4443-9A42-B77DE374E8FE</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

    
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>  
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#301934" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#301934" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />
    
    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[the file sturcture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOlJ8.png)

Comment: Android devices don’t have “d:” drives.  For this to work on all platforms you need to include the file in your project so it is deployed as part of the app

Comment: I reread your question and it looks like you are including it in the project (good) but are attempting to read it using the windows path (bad)

Comment: oh sorry it looks like I posted the wrong code but I tried that sitting it to (@"Resources\Raw\topics.txt") but it still didn't work

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android#bundled-files

Comment: thank you this appears to have worked